# Envió de solicitud con jquery dataTable

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, http

estoy intentando realizar una solicitud http con jquery datatable y el payload de la solicitud no la recibo en el endpoint del back. me fije que el payload viaja encriptado.

esta es la configuración del ajax de jquery dataTable

[image]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no pongas el código como imagen ponlo como texto, eso hará mas fácil que alguien te ayude

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.